# Во время выполнения тестов в Django Rest Framework тестовая база данных смешивается с реальной

Tags: python, django, postgresql, юнит-тесты, django-rest-framework

Возникла непонятная для меня проблема. Создаю приложение на DRF, для которого пишу тест. Тестовый класс тестирует страницу, которая выводит все данные модели. В  реальной базе данных две записи. В тестовой тоже две записи. Но они отличаются. Почему-то когда отправляю get запрос в тесте на страницу со списком данных, в объекте response содержится не только OrderDict содержащий тестовые данные указанные в методе SetUp, но и данные с реальной базы данных. База данных - PostgreSQL

Код тестов:

```
class BooksAPITestCase(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.book1 = Book.objects.create(name='Test book 1', price='1000')
        self.book2 = Book.objects.create(name='Test book 2', price='1000')
        self.serialized_data = BooksSerializer([self.book1, self.book2], many=True).data
        self.url = reverse('book-list')

    def test_response_status_code(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_get_page_data(self):
        response_data = self.client.get(self.url).data
        print(response_data)
        print(self.serialized_data)

        # response_data
        # [OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('name', 'War and Piece'), ('price', '1000.00')]),
        # OrderedDict([('id', 2), ('name', 'Crime and punishment'), ('price', '900.00')]),
        # OrderedDict([('id', 71), ('name', 'Test book 1'), ('price', '1000.00')]),
        # OrderedDict([('id', 72), ('name', 'Test book 2'), ('price', '1000.00')])]

        # self.serialized_data, полученная из тестов
        # [OrderedDict([('id', 71), ('name', 'Test book 1'), ('price', '1000.00')]),
        #  OrderedDict([('id', 72), ('name', 'Test book 2'), ('price', '1000.00')])]
```

Код Settings:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['XXX.iptime.org', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'testserver']

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'books_db',
        'USER': 'books_db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'тут пароль',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Возможно проблема кроется где-то на поверхности и я ее просто не замечаю, однако понять причину ошибки не могу. Есть подозрения, что такое может происходить из-за данных в списки ALLOWED_HOSTS, однако без них, по какой-то причине, тесты не запускаются в принципе.